# How to check if the user is already logged in?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

*I am complete new to `react-native` and Facebook `sdk`*

So I have followed the tutorial given [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) and everything works fine, the user is able to log in using facebook.

My question is :

**How do I check if the user is already logged in when he opens the app next time?**

I thought the callback `onLoginFinished` is called everytime regardless whether the user has already logged in or not. But that is not the case. If the user is logged in, the `onLoginFinished` not called. Is there any perticular callback to check that? or any other method or some workaround?

I tried to read the docs of `react-native-fbsdk` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native) but it seems they are not enough.

Here is the Login button:

```
<LoginButton
    onLoginFinished={ (error, result) => { this.handleLogIn(error, result) } }
    onLogoutFinished={() => { this.handleLogOut() } } 
/>
```

And the helper functions:

```
handleLogIn(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        alert("Login failed with error: " + result.error);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert("Login was cancelled");
    } else {
        alert("Login was successful")
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (data) => {console.log(data);} //Refresh it every time
        );
    }
}

handleLogOut() {
    console.log("User logged out");
    alert("Log out successful");
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to check if currentAccessToken is valid in the beginning somewhere appropriate when your app is started. If it returns null,  you need to refresh the token and if refresh token is expired, redirect user to loginpage.

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (data) => {console.log(data);} //Refresh it every time
        );
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you!

Comment: @agent_hunt how to check if access token is expired? Will accesstoken just be null?

Comment: According to docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension, this seems to be taken care off by SDK itself . There seems to  be a way to read expirationTime https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/accesstoken.html/#getexpires--    in the native android sdk but that is not exposed by the react-native-fbsdk

Comment: Does calling AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() refresh the token automatically? if it returns a token does that mean its good to use or do you need to test it somehow?

Comment: I get an nativeeventemitter is null warning, though it works. I am using it in the useEffect