# React-native facebook login button state

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have a react-native application that uses [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) for log in with facebook. I want to know how does the LoginButton provided by that library manage its state? Currently I'm trying it with android version.

If I login with the app, it logins correctly, and then button text changes from 'Continue with facebook' to 'Log out'. Now if I reload the application, and open it again, then the login button still reads 'Log out'. As if it has saved the previous state somewhere? I want to know where it has saved the state? How could I access it? Does it ask the login status under hood from facebook? Or how does it work?

This question is related to mine: [How to check if the user is already logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347645/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-already-logged-in)

Comment: Is there something you want to do but can't or you just want to know how it works? Is this is on iOS or Android? react-native-fbsdk it's using Facebook SDK that's handling the login state. On iOS It [caches the user's accesstoken](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/TokenCaching/FBSDKAccessTokenCacheV4.m#L66) using Keychain Services provided by iOS SDK.

Comment: It's on android. I want to know if the user is really logged in, even after reloading the app? Or does it just show like it? Because if it is really logged in, then I could open another page, instead of the login page. But I don't know how to check if the user is logged in or not. But since the LoginButton seems to know it locally, there has to be a way to get that information in the code as well, without sending any requests.

Comment: Have you tried the answer you linked in your question? To me it sounds right to use the AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() and accordingly as explained in the answer.