# Is User already have Permissions FB SDK react native

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I have a simple Question i just want to know that is user first time trying to logged in or else.
I am using react native fb SDK and Im enable to find any way.

I already try but not getting success.

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the user is already logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347645/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-already-logged-in)

Answer (score 0):

This is my login facebook function:
Step is:

- Get permission
- User login
- Get token

My code:

```
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
 const loginFacebook = () => {
  setTypeLogin(TYPE_LOGIN.FACEBOOK)
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    LoginManager.setLoginBehavior("web_only")
  }
  LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
    function (result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
      } else {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
          .then((data) => {
            setAccessToken(data.accessToken)
            prepareCallApi()
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
    },
  );
};
```

Comment: Im able to login or get all the information I just want to know that is user first time trying to   logged in FB or its already logged in.

Comment: Hmmm, this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347645/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-already-logged-in?